# С++ Нужно вывести на экран элементы расположенные ниже главной диагонали двухмерного массива

Tags: c++, массивы, числа

[image: массив]

n - размерность массива

выше диагонали все норм, а вот с нижней траблы
не могу понять откуда берется лишние

```
        \\Верхняя часть
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int b = i + 1; b < n; b++) {
                cout << mass[i][b];
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
        \\Нижняя часть
        for (int x = n; x >= 1; --x) {
            for (int h = x - 1; h >= 0; --h) {
                cout << mass[x][h];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как минимум если размерность массива - n, то

```
for (int x = n;
```

является выходом за границы массива (последний элемент имеет индекс `n-1`...

Comment: Спасибо) понял в чем моя проблема)

Comment: Тогда прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него (минут через 5).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"vvedite razmer matrici stroka i stolbec"<<endl;
    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    cout<<endl;
    double a[n][m];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<m;j++)
        { a[i][j]=rand()%10+1;
            cout<<a[i][j]<<"   ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;

   for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j <i; ++j)
        {
         cout << a[i][j]<<"  " ;
        }
}


return 0;
}
```